# Libjpeg write image to memory data

Tags: c++, libjpeg

I would like to save image into memory (vector) using libjpeg library.
I found there funcitons:

```
init_destination
empty_output_buffer 
term_destination
```

My question is how to do it safely and properly in parallel programs ? My function may be executed from different threads.
I want to do it in c++ and Visual Studio 2010.

Other libraries with callback functionality always have additional function parameter to store some additional data.
I don't see any way to add any additional parameters e.g. pointer to my local instance of vector.

**Edit:**
The nice solution of mmy question is here: http://www.christian-etter.de/?cat=48

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write to memory buffer instead of file with libjpeg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559648/write-to-memory-buffer-instead-of-file-with-libjpeg)

Comment: I found this post, but there is used one global vector and therefore it is not safe in parallel programs.

Comment: Did you look at the other answers?

Comment: I found nice solution here: http://www.christian-etter.de/?cat=48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice solution is described here: http://www.christian-etter.de/?cat=48

```
typedef struct _jpeg_destination_mem_mgr
{
    jpeg_destination_mgr mgr;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;
} jpeg_destination_mem_mgr;
```

Initialization:

```
static void mem_init_destination( j_compress_ptr cinfo )
{
    jpeg_destination_mem_mgr* dst = (jpeg_destination_mem_mgr*)cinfo->dest;
    dst->data.resize( JPEG_MEM_DST_MGR_BUFFER_SIZE );
    cinfo->dest->next_output_byte = dst->data.data();
    cinfo->dest->free_in_buffer = dst->data.size();
}
```

When we finished then we need to resize buffer to actual size:

```
static void mem_term_destination( j_compress_ptr cinfo )
{
    jpeg_destination_mem_mgr* dst = (jpeg_destination_mem_mgr*)cinfo->dest;
    dst->data.resize( dst->data.size() - cinfo->dest->free_in_buffer );
}
```

When the buffer size is too small then we need to increase it:

```
static boolean mem_empty_output_buffer( j_compress_ptr cinfo )
{
    jpeg_destination_mem_mgr* dst = (jpeg_destination_mem_mgr*)cinfo->dest;
    size_t oldsize = dst->data.size();
    dst->data.resize( oldsize + JPEG_MEM_DST_MGR_BUFFER_SIZE );
    cinfo->dest->next_output_byte = dst->data.data() + oldsize;
    cinfo->dest->free_in_buffer = JPEG_MEM_DST_MGR_BUFFER_SIZE;
    return true;
}
```

Callbacks configuration:

```
static void jpeg_mem_dest( j_compress_ptr cinfo, jpeg_destination_mem_mgr * dst )
{
    cinfo->dest = (jpeg_destination_mgr*)dst;
    cinfo->dest->init_destination = mem_init_destination;
    cinfo->dest->term_destination = mem_term_destination;
    cinfo->dest->empty_output_buffer = mem_empty_output_buffer;
}
```

And sample usage:

```
jpeg_destination_mem_mgr dst_mem;
jpeg_compress_struct_wrapper cinfo;
j_compress_ptr pcinfo = cinfo;
jpeg_mem_dest( cinfo, &dst_mem);
```